# Conditional expectation is monotonic

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $\mathcal{C}$ a sub- $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$, and $f,g \in L_1(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P, \mathbb R)$. I'm trying to prove the monotonicity of conditional expectation, i.e.,

> **Theorem:** If $f \le g$ a.e. then $\mathbb{E}[f | \mathcal{C}] \leq \mathbb{E}[g | \mathcal{C}]$ a.e.

Could you please verify my attempt?

**Proof:** Let $A := \{\mathbb{E}[f | \mathcal{C}] > \mathbb{E}[g | \mathcal{C}]\}$. Then $A \in \mathcal G$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_A (\mathbb{E}[f | \mathcal{C}] - \mathbb{E}[g | \mathcal{C}]) \mathrm d \mathbb P &= \int_A \mathbb{E}[f | \mathcal{C}] \mathrm d \mathbb P - \int_A \mathbb{E}[g | \mathcal{C}] \mathrm d \mathbb P \\
&= \int_A f \mathrm d \mathbb P - \int_A g \mathrm d \mathbb P \\
&\le 0.
\end{align}
$$

Notice that $\mathbb{E}[f | \mathcal{C}] - \mathbb{E}[g | \mathcal{C}] > 0$ on $A$. The proof is completed by applying below lemma.

---

> **Lemma:** Let $h \in L_1(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P, \mathbb R)$ and $A \in \mathcal F$. If $h>0$ on $A$ and $\int_A h \mathrm d \mathbb P \le 0$, then $\mathbb P (A)=0$.

**Proof:** Let $A_n := \{x \in A ; |h (x)| \ge 1/n\} \in \mathcal F$. Then $A_n \nearrow A$. By Markov's inequality,
$$
\mathbb P (A_n) \le n \int_A |h| \mathrm d \mathbb P = n \int_A h \mathrm d \mathbb P = 0.
$$

By continuity of measure from below, we get
$$
\mathbb P(A) = \lim_n \mathbb P(A_n) = 0.
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: Seems correct. A similar approach is to prove that if $\int_A f \geq 0$ (all $A$) then $f \geq 0.$ (If $f < 0$ on a bigger-than-zero mass set, then on that set the integral is negative.)